# Memory Pressure Protection Feature for TCP Stack - Provided by Microsoft Security Update KB967723

Tags: windows, security, tcp

We've been having a lot of funky issues with some of our web based applications that allow clients to submit lot of image files to our servers.  Lots of ports are used in the process.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/MS09-048.mspx - released in Sept-2009.

support.microsoft.com/kb/974288 - Memory Pressure Protection description.

Evidently, after applying KB967723, our clients receive funky error messages as if connections cannot be made to the server or connections have been closed.  There doesn't appear to be a pattern and sometimes it works and other times is doesn't.  Typically we've noticed it when server is under load.

I'm curious what others think about this MPP and any issues that you may have experienced from it.  I understand its purpose, but I think it may have broken a lot of apps in the process.  It doesn't look like Microsoft made this "feature" public to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I've got all my 2003 servers fully patched- no issues here.  I only have 1 app that makes gobs of connections (it's a url monitor).  It makes sense that you have the issues when it's under load since according to the article that's when it kicks in.  It also mentions however that you can disable it:

```
For example, you could follow these steps to disable the MPP setting on IPv4:
Click Start, click Run, type regedit in the Open box, and then click OK.

Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
Type EnableMPP, and then press ENTER.
Right-click EnableMPP, and then click Modify.
In the Value data box, type 0, and then click OK.
Exit Registry Editor.
Restart the computer
```

Have you tried this and did it help?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the clients first go thru another IIS server that proxies the connections over to the back-end web server.  So all the connections from the server having the issue are all coming from the same IP address.

Yes, all my servers are fully patched as well... but I havve had to rollback this patch a few times because of these issues.

Comment: just so I am clear, you had the patch installed, edited the regidstry to disable the patch and still had to uninstall it?

Comment: No, I have not done the registry trick yet to disable MPP.  I just learned of this feature and about disabling it the other day.